# Setting height and width for jcarousel items

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to set height for jcarousel item this way

```
.jCarouselLite ul li {height:300px;}
.lookbookbg img {max-height:100%;}
```

And html is quite typical

```
<div class="jCarouselLite">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <div class="lookbookbg lookbookbg1">
                    <img src="{{ 'lookbookbg1.jpg' | asset_url }}" />
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I get the needed height, but width goes ballistic. Containing li gets width larger than image and as a result, a lot of space between items (i need 0). I would set a static width, but a lot of lis have different width. Auto width doesn't do anything.
p.s.
actually using jcarousel light.

Comment: Too little info to answer your question. You need to post additional code and even better, a jsfiddle.

Comment: added html code to it

Comment: Have you tried '.jCarouselLite ul li {height:300px;width:100%}'? If your interested in a responsive version of this plugin, here is a fork of it on [Github](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite) that has a responsive option.

Comment: even more space. Btw, looks like that's the one i'm using.

Comment: Well, not enough info to help you without an example. You should make a jsFiddle with your code and css to get appropriate help on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size:cover;` or `background-size:100% 100%;`

Comment: How will cover work if the structure for jcarousellite does not use backgrounds? the structure is this: '<div class="any-class">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="image/1.jpg" style="width:150px; height:118px;"></li>', each li being a carousel item. see the [plugin page](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php)